# Personalization conditions only switching after refreshing the page (Sitecore 8.2)

Tags: personalization

I have personalizations to hide/show sublayouts on my page based on the field values in a user's profile. When one of the conditions is met, we see that the personalizations are working as expected (the component is hidden). However, when the user is updated, and the conditions are not met, we don't initially see the component being shown. Only after refreshing the page do we see the visibility being updated. I've checked and we don't have caching enabled on any of the components. Any help on this would be great. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Hi Emily - I just wanted to clarify, are you expecting the personalization rule to run _without_ reloading the page? As in, some ajax method updates the profile field on the user and the component should show? Or is it that its taking 2 loads of the page to get the component to display?

Comment: Hi, it's more that when the user goes back to that page (and their profile has been updated in the meantime) we expect for the component to display, but it's not. When we reload the page, we see the expected behavior. So the issue is that we should be seeing the component display on the first load rather than having to reload and then see it.